# Does knockout optimise for logical operators when evaluating data bindings?

Tags: optimization, knockout.js, boolean-logic, logical-operators

For instance, if I have:

```
<div data-bind="visible: viewModel.property1() || viewModel.property2()" />
```

... if `viewModel.property1()` is `true`, does knockout still evaluate `viewModel.property2()`?

Similarly, if we have:

```
<div data-bind="visible: viewModel.property1() && viewModel.property2()" />
```

... if `viewModel.property1()` is `false`, does knockout still evaluate `viewModel.property2()`?

If it does then I will bare this in mind when trying to optimise my bindings.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does short circuit.

The right hand side of the bindings is evaluated as a block of arbitrary javascript, and since && and || short cirtcuit in javascript...

Comment: Cool. I thought as much. Thanks for confirming this, Cody.